# How do I keep toastr.js notifications open when I load the next page?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, toastr

I'm working with asp.net ASPX pages. I've put [toastr.js](https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/) on my MasterPage. It works properly. I'm using it on a page with a Save button that stays on the same page like so:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "toastr", "toastr.info("Save successful.");", true);
```

and a Save&Continue button that saves and loads the next page like so:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "toastr", "toastr.info("Save successful.");window.location='NextPage.aspx';", true);
```

But, when I click the Save&Continue button it flashes the notification but then the next page loads and it's gone. No persistence across changing pages.

Maybe I'm fuzzy on javascript specifics but is there some asynchronous way to load the toast notifications so they aren't specific to a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about ASP.NET WebForms, but here are some things to consider:

The issue is that when you submit and process a form using server side code (C# in this case), the entire page reloads, including your javascript files. This is why the toastr disappears when you click Save&Continue.

The only thing that I can think of would be this:

The method that runs when you click Save&Continue, would need to pass the necessary information to the next page, so that page two would know to display the toastr instead of page1.

If you truly want to submit a record to the database, navigate away and have a toastr displaying the entire time, you may want to look into Single page applications (Allowing you to make asynchronous requests, with routing, while staying on the same page, allowing the JS to keep running without full page refreshes). Although this could mean rewriting your application, which might not be an option.

Comment: I'm giving you the answer because you defuzzed my mind. I knew it should be possible but was having a block. SPA was precisely the context in which my brain couldn't grok the solution. Thank you!